# Load external website in iFrame without enabling apache header module PHP

Tags: javascript, php, apache, iframe, cross-platform

I'm making an application in which user first choose his design and add items to its selected design. Then user publish the store he created on my domain. Then after my system generates a code which a user should copy in his/her website. And then my that script creates an iframe and loads the store which user selected on my website. The problem is that i have to enable `apache header module` on my server first and then only my site gets loaded on user's website. But i don't want to enable it. Isn't there any way to bypass this problem. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: The most convoluted set up I have ever seen

Comment: Isn't there any solution for it?

Comment: @Dagon - Can i use easyXDM for it?